# Create Typescript Type from Enum values

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm looking for a way to create a Typescript type from ENUM values.
Currently I'm having to manually construct the type and keep it in sync with the ENUM.

Is there a way to create a type as a oneof from ENUM values? End result being when I update the ENUM the type will automatically reflect it

```
enum FRUITS {
    APPLE = 'apple',
    PEAR = 'pear',
    ORANGE = 'orange',
}

// type Fruits = FRUITS;
type Fruits = 'apple' | 'pear' | 'orange';

// This works
const fruit: Fruits = FRUITS.APPLE;
// This also works
const fruit2: Fruits = 'apple';
```

The type will be used in these scenarios so both have to still work:

```
const fruit: Fruits = FRUITS.APPLE;

const fruit2: Fruits = 'apple';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always recommend staying away from `enum` unless the values are truly opaque, meaning you do *not* need any TS code outside the enum declaration to refer to the `number`/`string` as literal values.  (Actually I tend to stay away from numeric `enum` entirely, since all `number` values are assignable to them, see [microsoft/TypeScript#17734](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17734) among other issues)

For the specific use cases presented in your example, I'd be inclined to drop `enum` and  use a strongly-typed enumlike object instead:

```
const FRUITS = {
  APPLE: 'apple',
  PEAR: 'pear',
  ORANGE: 'orange',
} as const;
```

That allows `Fruits` to be defined programmatically:

```
type Fruits = typeof FRUITS[keyof typeof FRUITS];
```

And then everything in your example still works:

```
const fruit: Fruits = FRUITS.APPLE;
const fruit2: Fruits = 'apple';
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/MYewdgzgLgBAYgJQKoEkAqBlGBeGBvAKBhgEEAFMgGQFEAuGAcgEMAHFgGwFMGAaImMtRIJ6DFpyYAnXvwDyCEgDkA4nUYhJTMAHNufAL4wmEGKEhQA3AQJQAnuPiSArgEsoJ3HfEgAZvGToGADaANactr4wXpyRiKiYALpWBGbQMD7ObvRwme44-vEYAHTkVNRWqbAZrlAATNm5HoysHNwWQA)

Comment: That's brilliant. I had tried this approach before but without the `as const`. Without this it turns the type into a generic string which wasn't what I was after! Much appreciated!